# Mapping printer in another network through sonicwall

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I have a network A (say `192.168.1.x`) and network B (say `192.168.5.x`, both located at different places. I have also have sonicwall set up for these two places, where VPN is set such both networks could locate each other.

i.e. in the VPN section of sonic wall in network A, under settings, the gateway is set to a public IP of network B (e.g. `98.765.432.10`) and then destinations is set to `192.168.5.0-192.168.5.255`

Now, I am on network A. I open cmd and ping `192.168.5.0` and `192.168.5.200`. However, I could not ping to the printer ip `192.168.5.111`. Why is that so? How can I install/ map the printer in network B? (and thus do some printing...)

Comment: Does the printer have a default gateway configured in it's TCP/IP network settings?

Comment: default gateway is `192.168.5.1` and I could ping to that...

Comment: Do you mean that the default gateway configured on the printer is 192.168.5.1 and that the printer can ping the gateway?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the printer isn't configured with a default gateway. In that scenario your ping requests from "Network A" will travel to "Network B" to the printer. The printer, having no default gateway configured, won't be able to respond back to "Network B" because, without a default gateway configured, it has no ability to send packets to subnets other than the one it is attached to.

Have someone at the location where the pritner is located generate a configuration page from the printer. Look for the default gateway setting. I suspect it will be either unset, or set to something other than the correct "192.168.5.1" setting.